# Difference between Rexster and Neo4j

Tags: database, graph-databases

I am planning to write an app based on graph database, and ran into Rexste, Neo4j, and Orientdb. However, I am a little confused.

I think Neo4j and Orientdb are graph databases, and Rexster is a graph server-side framework, but not sure about their differences. Could anyone explain to me? In particular, what is Rexster?

Also, if I want to deploy on Heroku, which one should I use? Orientdb looks more fancy and advanced, but not as popular as Neo4j, and is not supported on Heroku. Is there a reason?

Comment: Rexster is a "graph server" in the sense that it can host one or more Blueprints-enabled graphs, like OrientDB or Neo4j.  It is not, by itself, a graph database.

Answer (score 0):

[Regster graph server](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Rexster-Graph-Server) is just a wrapper around your graph database to expose the database via a JSON-based REST interface

Neo4j and Orientdb are graph databases. 
I am not familiar with Heroku, but it says that it supports Java. Rexster has a java client so if you can expose your db via Rexster, you can use it with Java.

Again, I am not familiar with Heroku, but it seems like it is PAAS. So it will only run software supported by the platform (i.e. Java, Node.js, Scala, Clojure and Python). However, since it is based on Ubuntu Linux, you might find a way to run Linux software on it and these graph dbs are supported on Linux.

Also consider Titan graph db - it might be not as popular as the other ones you've mentioned, but seems good.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Regster is just wrapper and will not replace your graph database needs.

It sits on top of a graph database and expose additional functionalities, like:

- JSON interface,
- security,
- Admin UI,
- extensible REST endpoints ..

Regarding the two other choices, I am adding [here](http://db-engines.com/en/system/Neo4j;OrientDB) are [here](http://db-engines.com/en/system/Neo4j;OrientDB) two comparison maps between Neo4j and OrientDB, detailing the features of each of them.

In *very short*, OrientDB supports full replication while it seems Neo4j does not natively, but Neo4j would be more widely adopted, and has better documentation.

[Heroku itself](https://addons.heroku.com/graphenedb) exposes Neo4j as a service through the [GrapheneDB plugin](http://www.graphenedb.com/) and would be your de facto choice if you want to use a Graph database on Heroku.

Also the probable reason while OrientDB is not on Heroku yet, would be because no one is providing OrientDB as a Service yet